# header location(PHP) and query redirection or refresh page not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, redirect, header

Using .htacess file I rewrite url. working fine
Problem with session expire. I used ajax for checking session is expire or not. if expire redirect on login page.
    I used `<?php header('location: login.php'); die; ?>` 
    also try `

```
<script>function checkLohinOtherUser(){
       $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'login/dbc.php',
                data: '&do=checkLogin',
                success: function(rep){ 
                 var result = eval("("+rep+")");   
                 if(result == 1){  
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $('#pals_Schedule').hide();
                        $('#login-frame').html().show();
                         //window.location = "login/login.php";
                         window.location.href = 'login/login.php'; 
                 }, 1000); 
                 }
                }
            });
    }

    setInterval(function(){ checkLohinOtherUser(); //alert("Hello"); 
    }, 5000);
    </script>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
window.location.replace("http://localhost/login/login.php");
```